# Multithreaded processing while maintaining partial sequence

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost-asio

I have a message processing logic as follows:

```
boost::asio::io_service ioService;
boost::thread_group threadPool;

// Initialization code.
int noOfCores = boost::thread::hardware_concurrency();
for (int i = 0 ; i < noOfCores ; i ++)
{
    threadPool.create_thread(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, , &ioService)); 
}
```

Later in the socket reading thread, I receive messages and post a handler function while binding the received message.

```
ioService.post(boost::bind(MessageHandler, message));
```

The above line ensures that multiple messages can be processed simultaneously. However, it also loses sequential processing which might be desirable sometimes. In fact, since the processing time for messages can wildly vary, the sequence gets totally messed up.

For example, let's say I have messages of type A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I & J. I don't care at what order they are processed, so multi-threaded processing is perfect. However, I do need messages of same type processed in sequence. Let's say I received messages in the following order.

C1,E1,F1,A1,B1,C2,B2,D1,D2,F2,A2,H1,H2,A3,E2,E3,F3

Here, the alphabets are the type and the numbers are the sequence of their arrival. Different message types can be processed in parallel in any order, the sequence within the type should be maintained. I want A1 processed before A2, and A2 before A3. Same for every message type.

One of the way could be, to ensure that messages of a given type always goes to the same thread. It is not very efficient. If I have only 5 message types and 32 CPU cores, I will be still limited to 5 threads. Is it possible to force an item to be processed by a particular thread? Or else I have to maintain one queue per thread, deal with mutex locking, etc.

Is there any better way?

Comment: One queue and one atomic_bool (ready_to_be_processed) by type ?

Comment: If you have 5 message types, and they all needs to be process in sequence. you can never have more than 5 thread working at the same time, no matter what method you use.

Comment: Ok, let me look up atomic type, haven't used that one before. @Jarod42, I think you are saying keep only one message of any type in ready state in the queue? Turn on the next, when the current one is processed?

Comment: For `QueueA`, you can push event even if thread is processing (you have to synchronize to avoid to push and pop at the same time). popping A to process requires that flag `ready` is true, then atomically, set flag to false and pop next A to process; once finished, reset flag to true.

Comment: Ah, so I can have any number of threads, but one queue per type. The processing thread should mark the next item to be ready. Thanks a lot, let me try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [strand](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_context__strand.html) for each type of work as your queue.  That way your work can be spread across the io_context threads evenly and it provides the sequential work queue for each type of work and doesn't require any mutex locking.

Comment: Thanks. I think is lot simpler to implement than other options.

Comment: I implemented it in 15 minutes, it worked great. But there is one problem. Since it executes in different threads, A2 process launch doesn't wait for A1 process to complete. If A1 process takes long, A2 could complete first.

Comment: Your comment doesn't make sense.  If you have a strand instance for all work 'A'.  Posting work to strand 'A' will mean A2 will wait for A1 to complete before being started.  You can think of a strand  like a "thread" in that all work posted to it will be run in sequence (like on a single thread).

Comment: Hmm, you are right. Looks like I am losing the sequence in some other part of the code. I have an idea where, need to do intensive load testing to confirm it.